# Hive- Quicker way to check for data

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I have a scala/ spark package that operates on a Hive database. It runs a loop where a query is run to check if data exists for some particular values

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1 = 7879 AND col2= 1071 AND col3= 3027 LIMIT 1;
```

Then proceed based on whether or not it returns a row. It takes about 25 seconds to execute.

I've seen that this way works faster than

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE col1 = 7879 AND col2= 1071 AND col3= 3027;
```

and proceeding based on whether or not the count is 0.

Is there a faster way to check if data exists in a table for certain constraints?

**EDIT -** The loop is run based on the resulting rows of another query (resulting in 100+ rows).

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the loop.
Do all the checks in a single query.

There are various ways to write the query, this is one (assuming result_set_of_another_query as only unique combinations of (col1,col2,col3)).

```
select      q.col1
           ,q.col2
           ,q.col3
           ,t.cnt

from                    result_set_of_another_query as q

            join       (select      col1
                                   ,col2
                                   ,col3
                                   ,count(*)    as cnt

                        from        mytable

                        group by    col1
                                   ,col2
                                   ,col3
                        ) t

            on          t.col1 = q.col1
                    and t.col2 = q.col2
                    and t.col3 = q.col3
;
```

Answer (score 0):

if your table is partitioned than you can not use the where clasue . for ensuring that each partition is having proper data you can only run the count(*) in your table. You can also use union all if you want to check in multiple tables,